# How to resize the iframe base on the url content without scroll bar in iframe in java script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

In my application there is select drop down  box contain url while user select url from drop down .I need to load url in iframe with content size .I need to increase the height of iframe according to the content without scrollbar can anybod tell How to  resize the iframe base on the url content  without scroll bar in iframe?

Answer (score 0):

iframes aren't able to fit the size of their target content automatically. In other words: There is no "auto" value to the width or height of an iframe, you'll have to specify the size of the frame.

To solve this problem you'd have to know the size of the content upfront so you can pass it to your iframe alongside the chosen url. You could use data-attributes to do that.

HTML

```
<select id="frameURL"> 
  <option value="http://www.url1.com/" data-cheight="600">URL 1</option>
  <option value="http://www.url2.com/" data-cheight="750">URL 2</option>
  <option value="http://www.url3.com/" data-cheight="1200">URL 3</option>
</select>

<iframe scrolling="no" style="display:none;" id="myFrame" src=""></iframe>
```

JS / jQuery

```
$("#frameURL").change(function(){
  // get URL
  var target = $(this).find("option:selected").val(); 
  // default fixed Width of content area
  var cntWidth = 500; 
  // get content height from data-cheight
  var cntHeight = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-cheight"); 

  // pass all attributes to the iframe
  $("#myFrame").attr({
     src: target,
     width: cntWidth,
     height: cntHeight
  });

  // hide iframe when src attribute is empty / no URL chosen
  !$("#myFrame").attr("src") ? $("#myFrame").hide() : $("#myFrame").show();
});
```

**See working model here:** https://jsfiddle.net/xxgs901u/3/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access the content of an iframe from it's parent window. If the source of the iframes are internal pages of your application you could achieve this with [cross-document messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

In the iframe:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    parent.postMessage({ height: $('html').height(), width: $('html').width() }, "*");
});
```

In the parent:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create IE + others compatible event handler
    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];
    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

    // Listen to message from child window
    eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
        $('iframe').width(e.data.width);
        $('iframe').height(e.data.height);
    },false);
});
```

If needed you could send more resize events if the size of the iframe's content changes.

Comment: You have used two document ready function in index.jsp  i haved added iframe